# error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, clang, python-venv

I'm new to coding. I've encountered the error below while installing [py-sphviewer](https://github.com/alejandrobll/py-sphviewer) with `pip install py-sphviewer`. It works correctly and it installs it if I run the command in my main environment on the computer, but inside the venv of Pycharm it gives me this error. How can I solve it? Thanks!

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/user/PycharmProjects/project/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/1j/lzpq2tl51gbdxr6nbkpwsjt00000gn/T/pip-install-o60muxsn/py-sphviewer_f01b446b8415437295e5f4c739f1548b/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/1j/lzpq2tl51gbdxr6nbkpwsjt00000gn/T/pip-install-o60muxsn/py-sphviewer_f01b446b8415437295e5f4c739f1548b/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/1j/lzpq2tl51gbdxr6nbkpwsjt00000gn/T/pip-record-eniiwsv3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/user/PycharmProjects/project/venv/include/site/python3.8/py-sphviewer
         cwd: /private/var/folders/1j/lzpq2tl51gbdxr6nbkpwsjt00000gn/T/pip-install-o60muxsn/py-sphviewer_f01b446b8415437295e5f4c739f1548b/
    Complete output (40 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/sphviewer
    copying sphviewer/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/sphviewer
    copying sphviewer/Render.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/sphviewer
    copying sphviewer/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/sphviewer
    copying sphviewer/Scene.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/sphviewer
    copying sphviewer/Particles.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/sphviewer
    copying sphviewer/Camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/sphviewer
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/sphviewer/extensions
    copying sphviewer/extensions/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/sphviewer/extensions
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/sphviewer/tools
    copying sphviewer/tools/Blend.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/sphviewer/tools
    copying sphviewer/tools/hsv_tools.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/sphviewer/tools
    copying sphviewer/tools/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/sphviewer/tools
    copying sphviewer/tools/QuickView.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/sphviewer/tools
    copying sphviewer/tools/camera_tools.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/sphviewer/tools
    copying sphviewer/tools/cmaps.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/sphviewer/tools
    copying sphviewer/extra_code.c -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/sphviewer
    copying sphviewer/c_code.c -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/sphviewer
    copying sphviewer/README.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/sphviewer
    running build_ext
    creating var
    creating var/folders
    creating var/folders/1j
    creating var/folders/1j/lzpq2tl51gbdxr6nbkpwsjt00000gn
    creating var/folders/1j/lzpq2tl51gbdxr6nbkpwsjt00000gn/T
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -I/Users/user/PycharmProjects/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Users/user/PycharmProjects/project/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c /var/folders/1j/lzpq2tl51gbdxr6nbkpwsjt00000gn/T/tmpromdrtgo.c -o var/folders/1j/lzpq2tl51gbdxr6nbkpwsjt00000gn/T/tmpromdrtgo.o -fopenmp
    building 'sphviewer/extensions/scene' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/sphviewer
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/sphviewer/extensions
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -I/Users/user/PycharmProjects/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Users/user/PycharmProjects/project/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c sphviewer/extensions/scenemodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/sphviewer/extensions/scenemodule.o -std=c99 -w -ffast-math -I/Users/user/PycharmProjects/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -fopenmp
    clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-headerpad,0x1000 -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/sphviewer/extensions/scenemodule.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/sphviewer/extensions/scene.cpython-38-darwin.so -lgomp
    ld: library not found for -lgomp
    clang-12: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/user/PycharmProjects/project/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/1j/lzpq2tl51gbdxr6nbkpwsjt00000gn/T/pip-install-o60muxsn/py-sphviewer_f01b446b8415437295e5f4c739f1548b/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/1j/lzpq2tl51gbdxr6nbkpwsjt00000gn/T/pip-install-o60muxsn/py-sphviewer_f01b446b8415437295e5f4c739f1548b/setup.py'"'"';f
= getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/1j/lzpq2tl51gbdxr6nbkpwsjt00000gn/T/pip-record-eniiwsv3/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/user/PycharmProjects/project/venv/include/site/python3.8/py-sphviewer Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: I think the "real" error here is `ld: library not found for -lgomp`.  You probably need to install [gomp](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/gomp/).

Comment: @0x5453 How can I see where the library is in my computer? Since it was able to install it in my main environment, but it gives me this error only in Pycharm venv, it should already exist and I just need to add it in the path